# Gravitational force vs centripetal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

If you have a ball launching like this with an initial speed $v_0$ in a circular motion ($l$ is a string), at some point the ball won't follow this circular path anymore. From my understanding this happens when the tension in the string becomes 0.

and seen from the circular motion, I assumed: $$m  \frac{v^2}{r} = m  g  \cos \theta $$ but this thinking seems to be wrong.

So when does something stop circular motion?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Centripetal force]

In order for the mass $m$ to stay on its circular path, a centripetal force $F_c$ has to act on it:

$$F_c=\frac{mv_0^2}{l}$$

This force is provided by the component of $mg$ that is parallel to the string:

$$F_c=mg\sin\theta$$

When:

$$mg\sin\theta\geq \frac{mv_0^2}{l}$$

Or:

$$\boxed{ \sin\theta\geq \frac{v_0^2}{gl}}\tag{1}$$

Then the mass starts falling away from its circular path.

---

"ytlu" in the comments is correct that due to a change in potential energy the tangential velocity $v(\theta)$ decreases.

If the initial angle was $\theta_0$ then when the angle has become $\theta$, the energy balance is:

$$\frac12 mv(\theta)^2-\frac12 mv_0^2=mlg(\sin\theta_0 - \sin\theta)$$

So that:

$$\frac12 v(\theta)^2=\frac12 v_0^2+lg(\sin\theta_0 - \sin\theta)$$

The expression for $v(\theta)^2$ then needs to be used in $(1)$.

Comment: The speed $v ( \theta )$ may differ from $v_o$. The problem is finding the position that ball will fail to follow the circular motion. In the ascending part, the speed is decreasing lossing to the gravitational potential energy, such that it becomes too slow to keep up the circular motion.

Comment: @ytlu You are correct. I will edit later on. Thank you.

Comment: Gravity is not the only force.  The tension in the string contributes to both centripetal acceleration and tangential acceleration.

Comment: @nasu For circular motion, the tension of string is perpendicular to the velocity, therefore it won't change the speed.